# Simple Configurable Products Extension Bugs

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, simple-product, associated-products

I have used the **SCP extension** by **Organic Internet** for a while now and it has always served me well. However I have found today when I run the **price indexer** it is no longer picking up the **max and min prices** for the **simple products**.

Along with this when I go into a **configurable product** and look in the **associated products** section the products are showing as expected, however the **titles for the products are missing**. When I **disable the SCP** extension then the **product titles come back** again.

I am running magento 1.9.3.3 with SCP 0.8.2, any help would be much appreciated.